# How to create via sql and detect via ERRORLOG SQL Server 2008 Deadlocks

Tags: sql-server-2008, deadlock, monitoring

I am designing a monitoring program using HP Sitescope SIS.

The goal is detect deadlocks.

In doing so, I created a deadlock on an existing but nearly unused SQL Server 2008.

I used the following link:
http://panigorthi.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-deadlock-in-sql-server.html

Now the query has been running for over 23 hours. Would you then say the SQL Server cannot detect the deadlock?

How can I create a deadlock it can detect and kill?

What is an example output in the ERRORLOG when the deadlock is resolved?

Comment: You'll know the deadlock is detected because an error will be returned to whichever session is chosen as the deadlock victim.  Deadlocks are typically detected immediately, 23+ hours indicates you have not created a deadlock.  Did you follow the directions in the blog precisely?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link I read awhile back about retrieving deadlock information via extended events.
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/deadlock/65658/

My guess is that if your query is still running then you have blocking not a deadlock.  Are you sure you went back to session 1 and ran the additional update statement?